# Find sum of subsequences when passed to function F

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array of size N and integer K we need to find the summation of output of all the subsequences of length K when given to function F where
Function F is returning sum of the given subsequence * GCD the given subsequence.

Example : Let N=2 and K=1 and array has only two elements [1,2] then here answer is 5 as there are only two subsequence : [1],[2].

Output for subsequence [1] from function F is 1*1 = 1
Output for subsequence [2] from function F is 2*2 = 4

So total is 1+4=5.

How to find it for given array of length N and given integer K where both of them can range upto 10000 and array elements can range upto 50000.

Obviously this sum can be very large so we need to give output as module to very large prime number 998244353.

Comment: try with sliding window technique

Comment: @sajib Can you explain a bit more detail of it ?Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-sliding-technique/

Comment: @sajib How that will fit with this problem ?

Comment: Example:

N = 5 && K = 3.

A = 2 1 4 9 5

**Technique For Summation:**

You need to start from 1st position and end when you take K item.
For this example you need to take first 3 ( 2 1 4) item.

sum = `2 + 1 + 4` = `7`


Now when you move to `4th` position you need to subtract `1st` position to make sure you have 3 item.

`sum` = `sum + 9 - 2`  = `14`

Then when you move to `5th` position you need to subtract `2nd` position to make sure you have 3 item.

sum = `sum + 5 - 1` = `18`

Comment: for gcd. you need to kepp prime factor of every number. then calculate like this way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subsequence sum and GCD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010836/subsequence-sum-and-gcd)