# Subsequence sum and GCD

Tags: algorithm, subset, combinations, dynamic-programming, greatest-common-divisor

I came across this question on a programming challenge about a month ago, but the editorial wasn't released so I am asking it here.

There is an Array A of size N. Find the sum * GCD of K length subsequences of A.

Example:

> If A = [1, 2, 3] and K = 2,
>
> {1, 2} = 3(sum) * 1(GCD) = 3
>
> {1, 3} = 4(sum) * 1(GCD) = 4
>
> {2, 3} = 5(sum) * 1(GCD) = 5
>
> Ans => 3 + 4  + 5 = 12

[image: Problem description]

Answer (score 3):

Here it is from scratch (didn't test it thoroughly though):

Let `C[k, i, d]` be the number of all `k`-length subsequences of `A[1..i]` such that GCD for them is equal to `d`.

Then

```
C[k, i, d] = Sum(C[k - 1, i - 1, d']) + C[k, i - 1, d]
```

where summation is over all `d'` such that `gcd(A[i], d') = d`.

The first term (the sum) corresponds to the case when we take all the sequences from `A[1..i-1]` and attach `A[i]` to them. The last term - when we don't include the `A[i]`.

Let `S[k, i, d]` be the total sum of all `k`-length subsequences of `A[1..i]` such that GCD for them is equal to `d`.

Then

```
S[k, i, d] = Sum(C[k - 1, i - 1, d'] * A[i] + S[k - 1, i - 1, d']) + S[k, i - 1, d]
```

where summation is over all `d'` such that `gcd(A[i], d') = d`.

Then having `S[k, i, d]` and knowing all possible `d` values we can calculate the required value.

Comment: This much seemed obvious to me. But this answer would not meet the constraints. Just N*K can be 900,000,000, and `d` can be in the tens at least for the greater part of iteration, not to mention the extra time of building and maintaining that hash.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Hi. What's your take on the possibility of the question simply being about k consecutive elements?

Comment: @m69 I don't know but that's what was discussed in the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684555/find-sum-of-subsequences-when-passed-to-function-f

Comment: @גלעדברקן We discussed it here too :-) I'm still not sure.

Comment: @m69 we could have at least an `O(sqrt(range) * N)` solution in that case, which would be under 10,000,000.

Comment: @גלעדברקן yeah, you’re right, it’s hard to fit those limits

Comment: @algrid thank you for the succinct elaboration, though (I just had some clumsy python code around it and you beat me to it :)

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, I've worked out the details for consecutive elements, but I haven't posted an answer, because everyone seems convinced that it's about the strict definition of subsequence.